# Use next imported fonts on scss variables

Tags: next.js, next.js13, sass-variables

I'm working with Next13 and I'm having problems when I try to use Next font variable on my scss files.

This is my font declaration on `app/layout.tsx`:

```
const montserrat = Montserrat({
  weight: ['400'],
  style: ['normal'],
  subsets: ['latin'],
  display: 'swap',
  variable: '--font-montserrat'
});´
```

This is how I'm trying to declare a sass variable:

```
$font-body: var(--font-montserrat);
```

The other variables are working but when I try to associate this to a css font-family property, the font does not change and it stays with the default browser font.

I know I can use it on jsx element's className like this `className={montserrat.className}` but I would like to apply font-family on styles files.

Comment: hmm looks like there's not much choice for us but to load from google font or use other nextjs styling like css-in-js :(

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can go the traditional way using font-face:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myXfonts;
  src: url(myXfonts.woff);
}
```

Then declare your variable

```
$font-body: 'myXfonts';
```

I suppose no benefits from Next.js font optimization will apply, but it works.